# Why didn't the Istari participate in the Angmar wars?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, istari

The Istari were said to come to Middle-earth in the Second Age (the Blue Wizards) and the Third Age (Saruman, Gandalf and Radagast). So I'm wondering why didn't Saruman, Gandalf or Radagast help the Dunedain in their war against Angmar; seems the wizards could have made a huge difference and even save the Dunedain kingdoms from destruction.

So why didn't they help or participate?

Comment: How do you know they did not?

Comment: @Lexible "Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence," but in fictional universes the default assumption is that if something isn't mentioned, it didn't happen.  Or at the very least, it cannot be definitively said to have happened.  Maybe Picard spent a few years on the Klingon homeworld as an infant, but given that that's never said anywhere, we have to assume he didn't.

Comment: @Nerrolken That is **your** default assumption, not **the** default assumtpion. It's also rather absurd. Example: nothing is mentioned with respect to the Istari helping Angmar (or much of anything else the Istari did during this period). The default is that the Istari literally traveled too and fro befriending folks (see Darth Satan's answer) and **otherwise did nothing** during this time.

Comment: @Lexible I'm not saying that nothing unmentioned ever happens in fictional universes, I'm saying that if it's unmentioned, it's *possible* that it didn't happen. You questioned OP's assumption in the question, and I'm saying that since it is unmentioned, it's at least a legitimate question.

Comment: @Nerrolken - it's important to remember that Tolkien's was the *first* such fictional universe (as we know them today), and didn't necessarily operate according to "the Rules".  As the man himself said (Letter 153):  "...as if it were a report of 'real' times and places, which my ignorance or carelessness had misrepresented in places or failed to describe properly in others. Its economics, science, artefacts, religion, and philosophy are defective, or at least sketchy".  So therefore "if something isn't mentioned it's because Tolkien just left it out" is also a valid assumption.

Comment: @DarthSatan As I said in my previous comment, the point I was making is that OP's question is reasonable.  If something is unmentioned, it MIGHT not have happened.  It's not unreasonable to ask this question.  I know that Tolkien left out things that did happen, otherwise we have to assume that none of the Fellowship had childhoods.  But Lexible's comment questioned OP's post as though it didn't make sense, and I'm saying that a question about unmentioned events not happening *is reasonable.*

Answer (score 11):

They probably did, but if so it's not directly recorded.

In the Istari material in Unfinished Tales we read of Gandalf (with my emphasis):

> But the last-comer was named among the Elves Mithrandir, the Grey Pilgrim, for he dwelt in no place, and gathered to himself neither wealth nor followers, **but ever went to and fro in the Westlands from Gondor to Angmar**, and from Lindon to Lórien, befriending all folk in times of need.

So it's therefore almost certain that Gandalf at least **was** active in the resistance to Angmar.

Answer (score 3):

Because they were explicitly forbidden to use force. From the Tale of Years, describing the appearance of the Istari:

> It was afterwards said that they came out of the far West and were messengers sent to contest the power of Sauron, and to unite all those who had the will to resist him; but they were forbidden to match his power with power, or to seek to dominate Elves or Men by force and fear.

Comment: But the angmar wars were against the witch king, and we know that he fought them at weathertop so he could certainly battle with them just not sauron directly.

Comment: But the population of Angmar was Men.

Comment: I read somewhere recently that the Valar had a very bad record of sending people to Middle Earth to fight the bad guys directly.  So when they sent the Istari, they were limited in power and forbidden from directly fighting the bad guys.

Comment: This is technically true, but kind of misses the point.  The Istari could have had a huge influence against Angmar without raising a sword, just like they did during the Quest for Erebor and (mostly) the War of the Ring.  Their power lies (or is supposed to lie) in guidance and leadership, which is of course a valuable contribution in war.

Comment: @Jim2B - this is probably the Istari essay in Unfinished Tales: "And this the Valar did, desiring to amend the errors of old, especially that they had attempted to guard and seclude the Eldar by their own might and glory fully revealed; whereas now their emissaries were forbidden to reveal themselves in forms of majesty, or to seek to rule the wills of Men and Elves by open display of power".

Comment: @Darth You are probably right.  I read the Unfinished Tales for the first time back in 2013.